# How to obtain a reference to an input action?

Tags: unreal-engine5

I'm new to Unreal Engine and I'm currently working on binding a keypress to a method in a pawn class. Here's what I've done so far: I created a class called **FirstPawn.cpp** and an input mapping context named **IMC_my**. Within **IMC_my**, I added a single action called **MyAction** that corresponds to the **E** button keypress.

Now, the next step is to obtain a reference to the **MyAction** action in my code. I've been searching for a solution, but unfortunately, I haven't found an answer yet. It seems like it should be a straightforward task, but I could really use some guidance. Could you please assist me?

[image]

**FirstPawn.cpp**

```
#include "FirstPawn.h"

AFirstPawn::AFirstPawn()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
}

void AFirstPawn::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
}

void AFirstPawn::MyActionPressed()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("WOOHOO"));
}

void AFirstPawn::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
}

void AFirstPawn::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    UEnhancedInputComponent* Input = Cast<UEnhancedInputComponent>(PlayerInputComponent);

    // ERROR identifier "MyAction" is undefined
    Input->BindAction(MyAction, ETriggerEvent::Triggered, this, &AFirstPawn::MyActionTriggered);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - in your .h you need to have

```
public:
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Control|Input Actions")
        UInputAction* MyAction = nullptr;
```

Step 2 - you need to create a child Blueprint from your FirstPawn class.

Step 3 - you need to set your inputAction in the blueprint you just created

full video explanation:
[Getting Started With The Enhanced Input Features In UE5 (C++)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWnyDLn32wU)